# Android SeekBar setOnSeekBarChangeListener

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm wondering about the behavior of the android SeekBars OnSeekBarChangeListener. In particular, is the onProgressChanged-method notified only for the first and the last touch on the seekbar?

I'm trying to refresh a TextView that should show the current progress of the SeekBar. But the TextView is just updated on first touch and last touch. Debugging this confirms my assumption that this method is called just twice :( What I would like to have is that the TextView shows every progress change in the SeekBar.

In short: I am searching for a possibility to get a progress listener that is called for every little progress change.

Answer (score 101):

I hope this will help you:

```
final TextView t1=new TextView(this); 
t1.setText("Hello Android");        
final SeekBar sk=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);     
sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        t1.setTextSize(progress);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(progress),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }       
});
```

Comment: Also...posting what amounts to the same snippet of code multiple times within the same time frame is considered a bit spammy as well.

Comment: Can this done via XML? I'm unable to find an attribute for it.

Answer (score 14):

onProgressChanged() should be called on every progress changed, not just on first and last touch (that why you have onStartTrackingTouch() and onStopTrackingTouch() methods).

Make sure that your SeekBar have more than 1 value, that is to say your MAX>=3.

In your onCreate:

```
 yourSeekBar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.yourSeekBar);
 yourSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new yourListener());
```

Your listener:

```
private class yourListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
                            // Log the progress
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Progress is: "+progress);
                            //set textView's text
            yourTextView.setText(""+progress);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    }
```

Please share some code and the Log results for furter help.

Answer (score 8):

onProgressChanged is called every time you move the cursor.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(new Integer(progress)));        
}
```

so textView should show the progress and alter always if the seekbar is being moved.

Answer (score 4):

All answers are correct, but you need to convert a long big fat number into a timer first:

```
    public String toTimer(long milliseconds){
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString;
    // Convert total duration into time
    int hours = (int)( milliseconds / (1000*60*60));
    int minutes = (int)(milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60) / 1000);
    // Add hours if there
    if(hours > 0){
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }
    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if(seconds < 10){
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    }else{
        secondsString = "" + seconds;}
    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
textView.setText(String.format("%s", toTimer(progress)));        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override all methods

```
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seekbar called onProgressChanged method when we initialize first time. We can skip by using below code
We need to check boolean it return false when initialize automatically

```
volumeManager.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, i, 0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```