# How set SeekBar value on thumb moving only?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

When using SeekBar, the progress value can be set by touching anywhere. How do I make only thumb active and set the value only by moving the thumb?
In other words, the user can set the value in one touch in the right place of progress, and I need him to move the thumb.

Comment: Look at these answers perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956218/android-seekbar-setonseekbarchangelistener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SeekBar setOnSeekBarChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956218/android-seekbar-setonseekbarchangelistener)

Comment: No, this is different. I need the user not to be able to set the value with a single touch of progress, but to be sure to move the thumb!